# Windows: How to correct wrong month names in operating system level?

Tags: windows, datetime, localization, operating-system, abbreviation

We have an application that uses *AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames* to populate month names in a time line.

```
AddValuesToDictionary(resources, "dtpMonthShort", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames);
```

It seems, that the *CultureInfo*, specially *AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames* differ from Windows Server version to another. Worst of all, in Windows Server 2016, the *AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames* equals with *MonthGenitiveNames* thus creating bizarre behaviour in our time line control that has restricted space for each month.

The language I'm dealing with is Finnish. Here are some examples taken using Windows PowerShell with commands:

```
PS C:\> $C = Get-Culture
PS C:\> $C.DateTimeFormat

Windows Server 2012R2
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {tammi, helmi, maalis, huhti...}
MonthGenitiveNames               : {tammikuuta, helmikuuta, maaliskuuta, huhtikuuta...}

Windows Server 2016 Standard
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {tammikuuta, helmikuuta, maaliskuuta, huhtikuuta...}
MonthGenitiveNames               : {tammikuuta, helmikuuta, maaliskuuta, huhtikuuta...}

Windows Server 2019 Standard
AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames    : {tammik., helmik., maalisk., huhtik....}
MonthGenitiveNames               : {tammikuuta, helmikuuta, maaliskuuta, huhtikuuta...}
```

Our software should run on both Windows Server 2016 and 2019. I wouldn't like to recode correct month names in the application itself, as operating system is - and should be - providing the same information.

Also using *AbbreviatedMonthNames* instead of *AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames* is in my opinion out of question, since in [What is difference between MonthGenitiveNames and MonthNames? Why there is blank as month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675155/what-is-difference-between-monthgenitivenames-and-monthnames-why-there-is-blank) it is written "In short MonthNames are used in contexts where there is no day and GenitiveMonthNames are used in contexts where there is a day." Our time line shows the day together with month name.

Finally to the question: Is there any possibility to correct AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames in the Windows Server 2016 operating system afterwards it has been installed?